# How to render the count of like button every time it changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxUXL.png)I have created a like button and on clicking I am sending the event to backend to update the post and send the updated post back but I am not able to render the updated post.

**After loading the post it is transferred as parameter to this page**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import "./PostCard.css";
import Person4Icon from '@mui/icons-material/Person4';
import FavoriteIconfrom '@mui/icons-material/Favorite';
import HeartBrokenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/HeartBroken';
import ForumOutlinedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ForumOutlined';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { likeDislike } from '../../actions/postAction';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

const PostCard = ({post}) => {
    // console.log(post);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { like } = useSelector((state) => state.likePost);
   
    
    const { isAuthenticated, user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
    const [likeCount, setLikeCount] = useState(Object.keys(post.hearts).length);
    var isLiked=false;
    if(isAuthenticated){
        isLiked = Boolean(post.hearts[user._id]);
    }
    
    

    const likes = () => {
        dispatch(likeDislike(post._id));
        setLikeCount(Object.keys(post.hearts).length);
        console.log(like.hearts);
        console.log(Object.keys(like.hearts).length);
    }

   

    const dislikes = () => {
        dispatch(likeDislike(post._id))
    }

  return (
    <Fragment>
        
        <div className='card'>
            <div className='profile_icon'><Person4Icon 
            style={{color: post.avatarColor}}
            /></div>
            <div className='post'>
            <Link className='card_head' to={`/comment/${post._id}`}>
                <h4 
                style={{color:"orange"}}
                >{post.userName}</h4>
                <p>{post.post}</p>
            </Link>
                <div className='post_footer'>
                <Link className='card_head' to={`/comment/${post._id}`}>
                    <div className='post_footer_button'>
                        <ForumOutlinedIcon/>
                        <span className='number'>{post.comments.length}</span>
                    </div>
                </Link>
                    <div className='post_footer_button'>
                        <HeartBrokenIcon onClick={dislikes}/>
                        <span className='number'>{post.condolences.length}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className='post_footer_button'>
                        <FavoriteIcon onClick={likes}/>
                        <span className='number'>{likeCount}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className='break'>
            
        </div>
        
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export default PostCard
```

**Action part of the dispatch of like event**

```
//Likes Dislikes
export const likeDislike = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: LIKE_POST_REQUEST });

        const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
    
        const { data } = await axios.put(`/social/like`, {id}, config);
        
        console.log(data);
    
        dispatch({
          type: LIKE_POST_SUCCESS,
          payload: data.updatedPost,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: LIKE_POST_FAIL,
          payload: error.response.data.message,
        });
      }
}
```

**Reducer for updated like post**

```
export const likePostReducer = (state = {like: {}}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LIKE_POST_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case LIKE_POST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        like: action.payload,
      };
    case LIKE_POST_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: null,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Server side updating post**

```
exports.likePost = catchAsyncErrors(async(req,res,next) => {

    // console.log(req.body);
    const {id} = req.body;
    const post = await Post.findById(id);
    const user = await User.findById(req.user._id); 
    const isLiked = post.hearts.get(user._id);

    if (isLiked) {
        post.hearts.delete(user._id);
    } else {
        post.hearts.set(user._id, true);
    }
    const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
        id,
        { hearts: post.hearts },
        { new: true }
    );
                 
    res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        updatedPost,
    });

});
```

**Parent Component of Post Card**

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import "./Home.css";
import PostCard from '../Layout/PostCard';
import CreatePost from '../Layout/CreatePost';
import { getPosts, clearErrors } from '../../actions/postAction';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import {toast} from "react-toastify";
import Loader from "../Loader/Loader";
import { CREATE_POST_RESET } from '../../constants/postConstants';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {

 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const navigate = useNavigate();
 const { loading, error, posts } = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
 const { success } = useSelector((state) => state.createPost);
 const { isAuthenticated } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
 // console.log(user);

 const open = () => {
   if(isAuthenticated===false){
     toast.error("Login first");
   }

   if(isAuthenticated){
     navigate("/createPost");
   }
 }
 
 useEffect(() => {
   if(error){
     toast.error(error);
     dispatch(clearErrors());
   }
   if (success) {
     toast.success("Posted");
     dispatch({ type: CREATE_POST_RESET });
   }
   dispatch(getPosts());
 },[dispatch, success, error]);
 
 return (
   <Fragment>
       {loading ? (
         <Loader/>
       ) : (
         <Fragment>
           <div className='home'>
             <div className='home_left'>
                 <div className='home_heading'>
                   <h4>Try something here</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div>
                   {posts &&
                     posts.map((post) => {
                       return(
                         <PostCard key={post._id} post={post} />
                       );
                     })}
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div className='home_right'>
                 <CreatePost/>
             </div>
           </div>

           {/* FLOATING BUTTON */}
           <div className='floating_button'>
               <button onClick={open}>
                   <AddIcon/>
               </button>
           </div>
         </Fragment>
       )}
   </Fragment>
 )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: you are dispatching the likeDislike to the slice and setting the local according to the post.hearts, however post is being passed to this component as prop, does the post  likes count update in the parent component according to what's in the redux store (useSelector)? 
could you maybe share also the parent component of PostCard?

Comment: @Tomer_Ra I have updated the post, could you please check it now.
I know the post likes is not getting updated in the parent component, could you please suggest a way to do that

Comment: is the updatedPost here containing the new likes count? dispatch({type: LIKE_POST_SUCCESS, payload: data.updatedPost,});
- check in your log here - console.log(data);

Comment: @Tomer_Ra yes it is getting updated. I will attach the screenshot.